# Filtering on string starting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, indexof

I have a search bar to show the rows with a cell that contains a specific value, but I only want the ones that start with that value, only if they start with it, not if they contain it in the middle of the string.

This is what I have:

```
var $rows = $('#tableID tbody tr');

$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $('.filterClass', this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

Comment: @jcuenod done! I couldn't do it before, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What your code does:** You are using `indexOf` to test for the *presence* of `val` (the [`~` operator](https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/) is converting `-1` to `0` which is ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and so `!~text.indexOf(val)` is basically testing whether `val` is anywhere in `text`).

**Solution:** just check if `indexOf` is `0` (in other words, the `val` is begins at index `0` in `text`):

```
var $rows = $('#tableID tbody tr');

$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $('.filterClass', this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return text.indexOf(val) !== 0;     // <-- Note this line
    }).hide();
});
```

**Side Note:** It is simpler to understand code that means "*only show the rows like this*" than to understand "*hide all the rows that are not like this*". I would suggest changing your code's structure like this:

```
 $rows.hide()
 $rows.filter(/* your filter code */).show()
```

(this would mean removing the exclamation mark from the return statement as well)

Comment: This solved my problem! Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the result of `indexOf()` is equal to `0`. Instead of `!~text.indexOf(val)` use `text.indexOf(val) !== 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a possiblitly to use with the combination of a filter link like: A,, B, C?

Then make under search input `<a href="#A">`

And start filtration on this "word"?

```
var $rows = $('section article');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();});
```

Comment: Thans for you aswer Michał Perłakowski but how i can make a link with it?